# Bootstrapping Swap Curve

Tags: swaps, quantlib, interest-rate-swap, bootstrapping

I am trying to get the zero rates from the swap curve for chilean pesos (vs Camara). I tried this code (from a previuos question similar to mine from other person) and I am very close to get the result. But somehow I always get a zero rate 1 to 2 basis points below the real zero rate. This is happening even on other indexes.

**The result I get**

[image]

**The result I expect**

[image]

**Info about the index in case you don't know it**

[image]

**The code**

```
fecha = "2020-09-30"


tasa_clp1 = (0.50,0.475,0.475,0.49,0.62,0.78,0.99,1.28,1.53,1.79,1.9,2.16,2.295,2.52,2.62)#list(tasa_clp.iloc[:,0])
    #tasa_clf1 = list(tasa_clf.iloc[:,0])


def create_calendar_chile(start_year,n_years):
    Chile = ql.WeekendsOnly()
    days = [1]
    months = [1]
    name = ['Año Nuevo']
    for i in range(n_years+1):
        for x,y in zip(days,months):
            date = ql.Date(x,y,start_year+i)
            Chile.addHoliday(date)
    return Chile


def get_curve(date,swap,currency = 'CLP'):
    calendar = create_calendar_chile(2020,50)
    dayCounter_Act360 = ql.Actual360(includeLastDay=True)
    settlement_days_icp = 2
    # OIS quotes up to 20 years
    ICP = ql.OvernightIndex("ICP", settlement_days_icp, ql.CLPCurrency(),calendar, dayCounter_Act360)
    fixingDays = 0

    if currency == 'CLP':
        # setup DepositRateHelper for 0-1 days
        TPM = swap[0]
        months = [3,6,12]
        swap_month = swap[1:4]
        years =[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,20]
        swap_years = swap[4:]
        helpers = [ql.DepositRateHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(TPM/100)),
                                         ql.Period(1,ql.Days), fixingDays,
                                         calendar, ql.ModifiedFollowing, False, ql.Actual360(includeLastDay=False))]
    else:
        months = [3,6,12]
        swap_month = swap[1:4]
        years =[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,20]
        swap_years = swap[4:]
        helpers = []

    # setup OISRateHelper from 3 months to 20 years
    helpers += [ql.DepositRateHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate/100)),
                ql.Period(months,ql.Months),
                settlement_days_icp,
                calendar,
                ql.ModifiedFollowing,
                False,
                ql.Actual360(includeLastDay=True))
                for rate, months in zip(swap_month,months)]

    helpers += [ql.OISRateHelper(settlement_days_icp, ql.Period(years,ql.Years),
                                     ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate/100)),ICP)
                                     for rate, years in zip(swap_years,years)]

    icp_curve = ql.PiecewiseLinearZero(date, helpers, ql.Actual360(includeLastDay=True))
    icp_curve.enableExtrapolation()
    return icp_curve
def print_zero(date,yieldcurve):
    day_count = ql.Actual360(includeLastDay=True)
    spots = []
    dates = []
    tenors = []
    df = []
    for d in yieldcurve.dates():
        yrs = day_count.yearFraction(date, d)
        df.append(yieldcurve.discount(d))
        dates.append(d)
        compounding = ql.Compounded
        freq = ql.Annual
        zero_rate = yieldcurve.zeroRate(yrs, compounding, freq)
        tenors.append(yrs)
        eq_rate = zero_rate.equivalentRate(day_count,compounding,freq,date,d).rate()
        zero_rate.equivalentRate(day_count,compounding,freq,date,d).rate()
        spots.append(100*eq_rate)

    datatable = {'Dates':dates,'Years': tenors,'DF':df,'Zero': spots}
    datatable = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(datatable)
    print(datatable)

#Eval. Date
date_ql = ql.Date(int(fecha[8:]),int(fecha[5:7]),int(fecha[:4]))
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = date_ql
swap_clp = tasa_clp1#[2.5, 2.48, 2.47, 2.48, 2.53, 2.64, 2.82, 3.17, 3.43, 3.62, 3.81,3.96, 4.09, 4.19, 4.29, 4.45, 4.62]
yieldcurve_clp = get_curve(date_ql,swap_clp, currency = 'CLP')
print_zero(date_ql,yieldcurve_clp)
```

Comment: Why do you use a holiday calendar with weekends only? If I look at the fixing info (CLICP Index), it seems to observe the usual CL holiday calendar (e.g. from CDR on Bloomberg). Just curious - I doubt this affects the difference in zero rates you observe.

Comment: Because there is no calendar for Chile. So you have to create one, for simplicity I only added the new year as holiday, does not change really

At least that's what I understand about the library until now

Comment: Thanks, Ewald.- I need to create one myself for both Chile and Thailand (also missing in QLNet).